# Почему срабатывает деструктор?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, перегрузка-операторов

**clarray.h**

```
 #ifndef CLARRAY_H
 #define CLARRAY_H
 #include <iostream>
 #include <QString>

 using std::cout;
 using std::cin;
 using std::endl;

 class array
 {
 private:
    int* ptr;
    int size;
    QString name = "tmp_obj";
 public:
    array(int s, QString name){
        size = s;
        ptr = new int[s];
        this->name = name;
    }
    array(int s, int* p){
        size = s;
        ptr = p;
    }

    ~array(){
        cout << "destructor " << name.toStdString() << endl;
        delete[] ptr;
     }

     int& operator[](const int& j){
        return *(ptr+j);
      }

     array operator=(const array& cl){
        if(this!= &cl){
             size = cl.size;
             delete[] ptr;
             ptr = new int[size];
             *ptr = *cl.ptr; // для отладки пусть size == 1
         }

         cout << "= " << *this->ptr << endl;
         return *this;
    }
 };

 #endif // CLARRAY_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <clarray.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const int ASIZE = 1;
    array *cl = new array(ASIZE, "c1");
    array *c2 = new array(ASIZE, "c2");

    for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
        (*cl)[i] = i*i;

    *c2 = *cl;
    //сразу после присваивания срабатывает деструктор c2
    for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
        cout << "c1: " << (*cl)[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++)
        cout << "c2: " << (*c2)[0] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    delete cl;
    delete c2;
   // return a.exec();
}
```

**Output**

```
= 0
destructor c2
c1: 0
c2: -572662307
destructor c1
destructor c2
```

Ещё кидает исключение **_crtisvalidheappointer(block)**, как я понимаю из-за того что я обращаюсь к освобожденному участку памяти.

Вопрос: почему сразу после присваивания срабатывает деструктор?

Comment: Попробуйте привести программу к виду [mcve]. И ознакомьтесь с ["правилом трёх"](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор присваивания данного класса возвращает временный объект, который и удаляется после вызова этого оператора присваивания.

```
 array operator=(const array& cl){
 ^^^^^^
    if(this!= &cl){
         size = cl.size;
         delete[] ptr;
         ptr = new int[size];
         *ptr = *cl.ptr; // для отладки пусть size == 1
     }

     cout << "= " << *this->ptr << endl;
     return *this;
}
```

Кроме того в результате данного предложения

```
*ptr = *cl.ptr; // для отладки пусть size == 1
```

имеется утечка памяти.

Также ваш класс определен таким образом, что трудно определить, сколько элементов динамически распределенного массива было инициализировано, а сколько нет. В общем случае в данном операторе присваивания вы должны копировать актуальные элементы массива, находящегося в правой части от знака присваивания в целевой массив.

Что касается вызова деструктора, то вам следует объявить оператор присваивания следующим образом, то есть возвращать ссылку на объект

```
 array & operator=(const array& cl);
      ^^^
```

Данный конструктор

```
array(int s, int* p){
    size = s;
    ptr = p;
}
```

также неверный, так как объект класса должен динамически выделять память для своего массива. Иначе возникает коллизия: кто является владельцем указателя, и кто ответственен за удаления массива, адресуемого указателем?

К тому же вам следует также определить конструктор копирования.

Что касается конструкторов, то вы могли бы определить их следующим образом

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

array(int s, QString name) : size( s ), name( name )
{
    ptr = new int[s];
    std::fill( ptr, ptr + size, 0 );
}

array(int s, int* p) : size( s )
{
    ptr = new int[s];
    std::copy( p, p + s, ptr );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотрите сами: что возвращает ваш оператор?

```
array operator=(const array& cl){
     ...
     return *this;
}
```

Именно! `array`, а не ссылку на него. Так что `return *this;` вызывает конструктор копирования, и возвращает копию - объект `array`... который тут же уничтожается - он вам оказался не нужен.
Ну, а раз конструктора копирования у вас нет, то вызывается конструктор копирования по умолчанию - который копирует указатель (т.н. поверхностное копирование). Деструктор его удаляет, и ваш `с1` остается с указателем на удаленную память...

Вот и всё.